# Why is '1 + lambda: 1' a SyntaxError but '1 + (lambda: 1)' a TypeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, syntax

In the interactive interpeter the following two expressions raise different errors depending on the addition of parenthesis:

> `1 + lambda: 1` results in a `SyntaxError`

```
>>> 1 + lambda: 1
  File "<ipython-input-17-ae284d908963>", line 1
     1 + lambda: 1
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> `1 + (lambda: 1)` results in a `TypeError`

```
>>>> 1 + (lambda: 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```

I understand the differences `SyntaxError` and `TypeError`, that is, what they essentially mean, but I don't really understand why exactly this happens.

I have tried [reading](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) **[the Grammar](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Grammar/Grammar)**, but it really is all Greek to me. The `expr` (which I would of though denotes expressions) is defined as:

```
expr: xor_expr ('|' xor_expr)*
```

While lambdas:

```
lambdef: 'lambda' [varargslist] ':' test
```

These did not help much. The same applies for Python 2.x and for 3.x. So, why do parenthesis do that alters the exception result in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does `1 + lambda: 1` raise a `SyntaxError` ?

The syntax error is raised because the grammar doesn't support it. From the [Full Grammar Specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) we can see that the `test` rule, which [is the basic expression element](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm) *and not the ill-named `expr`*, has the form of:

```
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
test_nocond: or_test | lambdef_nocond
```

where [the vertical bar `|` is used to seperate alternative substitutions for this rule](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation).

As a result, each expression must either begin with an **[`or_test`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)** **or** a **[`lambdadef`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)**. If a `lambdadef` is not found in the beginning of an expression a `SyntaxError` is appropriately raised during parsing:

```
>>> import parser; parser.expr('1 + lambda: 1') 
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[**Note**: From the `or_test` member of `test` we can generate practically every other expression in Python by substitutions]

---

> Why does `1 + (lambda: 1)` raise a `TypeError` ?

Because parenthesis are used as [`enclosures`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atoms):

```
enclosure ::=  parenth_form | list_display | dict_display | set_display
               | generator_expression | yield_atom
```

where **[`parenth_form`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-parenth_form)** is:

```
parenth_form ::=  "(" [expression_list] ")"
```

The parenthesis here will isolate the `lambda: 1` from the rest of the expression and confine it in an expression (`test`) of its own. Since the new expression is `(lambda: 1)` it is syntactically valid (*since `lambdadef` is an element at the beginning of the expression*). As such, there is no rule which can trigger a `SyntaxError`. (if you did `1 + (1 + lambda: 1)` the same `SyntaxError` is triggered).

Additionally, we can actually verify the fact that `(lambda: 1)` is a new `test` rule by looking at (*the relevant section*) of the list-based parse tree and cross-referencing it with the numbers contained in **[`Include/graminit.h`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/graminit.h)**.

We can generate the parse tree from:

```
>>> parse_tree = parser.expr("1 + (lambda: 1)")
>>> parse_tree.tolist()

# further up the list, another [304, exists, denoting the 
# 'outer' expression

#.. snipped ..
            [323,
             [7, '(', 1, 4],
             [324,
              [304,   # <-- indicating new expression
               [306,
                [1, 'lambda', 1, 5],
                [11, ':', 1, 11],
#.. snipped ..
```

and by viewing the [definition for `test`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/graminit.h#l51) we can see that `304` defines a new `test`.

As a result, the expression will be parsed and consequently compiled with no issues:

```
>>> code_obj = parse_tree.compile()
```

It is during execution were the evaluation will happen and Python will discover that addition is unsupported for the objects of `int` and `function`. When it discovers it, a `TypeError` is raised:

```
>>> exec(code_obj)
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```